# Can't inject factory service from another module in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, ionic-framework

I am new to angularjs.

I am trying to build a mobile application inspired from modular approach defined here:

http://thaiat.github.io/blog/2014/02/26/angularjs-and-requirejs-for-very-large-applications/

Now I am trying to create a service using factory method in one of my modules `core`. I have another module called `home`. Now when I try to inject service from `core` to `home`, I get an error:

`Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: glue.core.geoLocationServiceProvider <- glue.core.geoLocationService`

I have searched through internet and here. None of the solutions are working for me.

the code of my `home` module's `controller` is:

```
define([
    '../module',
    '../namespace',
],
function(module, namespace) {
    'use strict';

    var name = namespace + ".homeController";
    var dependencies = ['$scope', '$http', '$ionicLoading', 'glue.core.geoLocationService'];
    var controller = function($scope, $http, $ionicLoading, core) {

    }

    module.controller(name, dependencies.concat(controller));

});
```

I have also uploaded the project here on github: https://github.com/neerajsohal/test/tree/development

Any help would be great. I am going mad with this.

Comment: Are you sure you're loading the `geoLocationService`? I just searched through the repository and can't find anything for it.

Comment: yes I am, I am creating it with name: `glue.core.geoLocationService`. Can be found here: https://github.com/neerajsohal/test/blob/development/app/core/services/geoLocationService.js

Comment: well I just solved it myself. Moved the core module folder to another location. It is working now. Thanks though! for help!

Comment: actually, the problem was with the name of the service, I changed it to `locationService` and it is working without moving folders around. Weird!

Comment: Something is very, very wrong with Ionic in this regard. Perfectly fine factory declarations all fail to resolve in my project, even though there is absolutely nothing wrong with the code itself. The services are simply not found.

Comment: I agree. I am still facing a lot of issues with ionic. I hope the updates would help or they would post examples in docs.